# How to use virtual folder structure url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtual-directory

I have url like this

```
http://www.abcdef.com/somthing.php
```

i want use same file content but different url format like this

```
http://www.abcdef.com/exp/go/to/123
```

for this where i need to modify either php or htaccess file?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: for seo purpose @anubhava

Comment: Really so `/exp/go/to/123` is more SEO friendly than `/somthing.php`

Comment: not like that we have different pages like this we need index them in google thats why trying to do like this @anubhava

Comment: ok then below answer should work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .htaccess file

for your example you'd use:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect ^/exp/go/to/123$ /somthing.php [L]
```

The main reason you'd use the "/exp/go/to/123" URL structure is because the different elements can be used as variables to load the page in which case you could use:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect ^/exp/go/to/([0-9]+)$ /somthing.php:id=$1 [L]
```

which will take the 123 off the url and pass it to the someting.php as an ID parameter.